# Should we "censor" bad-quality/insulting questions by editing them?

Tags: discussion

I just saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22410490/1) demanding our help, telling that the OP doesn't care if this is a duplicate and instead of insulting him/her, he/she will do it first.

First, I thought about editing the question by removing all this "intro". I didn't, but someone else did.

Should we edit (censor), downvote, or flag such questions?

Comment: It is not censoring to edit a question to contain only material that is actually a question. Meta talk like "I am new" or "please be nice" or "screw you all do my work for me" is all equally eligible to be edited away. If you prefer, you can downvote, and possibly remove that downvote when someone else cleans up the question. Don't flag; flagging is for things only a moderator can deal with.

Comment: Downvote. Closevote. Walk away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering I edited it: yes, I think we have to.

It is very likely that the question will get buried in down- and closevotes and will be stuffed away in a little corner.

It is also likely that the asker will not return to the question to try and make something constructive out of it.

None of this should stop us from simply removing the rant and carrying on with our day: it's very little effort and nobody that follows you has to waste time reading that stuff.

If you feel it is offensive: flag it. If you just think it's a poor question: downvote it. If you think it is not suitable here: closevote it.

Comment: After thinking about your answers and comments, I believe this was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 6):

It's noise.  It's not *offensive* or *insulting* (both of which would warrant flagging), just noise.  In the same sense that a signature, a "hello how are you doing today?", etc. is also noise, despite not being "insulting".  You are free to edit such unrelated content out of a post.

The only reason I'd consider flagging this is if the author continued to roll back the edits or re-apply the intro, in which cases a moderator is needed to prevent an edit war.